# Error when path is added to libraries in Qt Creator in Linux

Tags: linux, qt, shared-libraries, qt-creator

If I make a new Qt Widget Application  in Qt Creator 4.6.0 in Linux and add the following line to the pro file:

```
LIBS += -L/opt/MATLAB/R2018a/sys/os/glnxa64
```

it compiles without any issue, but it does not run. It shows this Segmentation fault error:

[image]

Here is a list of files in `/opt/MATLAB/R2018a/sys/os/glnxa64`:

```
libgcc_s.so.1
libgfortran.so.3
libgfortran.so.3.0.0
libifcore.so.5
libifport.so.5
libimf.so
libintlc.so.5
libiomp5.so
libirc.so
libquadmath.so.0
libquadmath.so.0.0.0
libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++.so.6.0.22
libsvml.so
README.libstdc++
```

Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

Comment: the line in your QMAKE file looks correct, could you post your code as well?  Since this seems to be a runtime issue

Comment: There is no code. As i mentioned in my question, I just make a `new` Qt Widget Application and add the LIBS line in my pro file.

Comment: Here is something that may be useful, http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/27854-Running-Application-linking-with-shared-libraries-in-Qt-Linux A user provided an example where not only is the path set with -L but also the individual library names with -l like so                 LIBS += -Lpath -lname

Comment: Why downvote?!?

Comment: @138 what if you don't specify the file name? Does it look for allof the files in the path? Why am I getting this error?

Comment: There is no code at all? If you are using Qt Creator, this will autogenerate cpp and qml files. If you are not receiving a compile/link error then the project could find those object files. Seqfault errors usually occur when you attempting to use an allocated pointer, which is runtime. Changing the build configs will not fix this part of the issue.

Comment: I do not modify the newly created application. So it does not have any code other than the auto generated one. As soon as I add the LIBS in the pro file, the application does not run. It shows the error in the snapshot.

Comment: But in runs without the libs? If so, that's strange, let me try some stuff and I'll come back. Where did you get the MATLAB sources? One thing can you try using QMAKE_LIBDIR instead of libs?

Comment: I installed Matlab. Yes, it does run without LIBS as it is a new untouched application.

Comment: does your installation of matlab work? Im assuming it does, but just wondering, also heres another potential search point https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/243816-segmentation-fault-when-starting-matlab

Comment: Matlab runs fine with no error. If I change LIBS to point to `MATLAB_INSTALL_PATH/bin/glnxa64`, Qt runs the application without any error. Linking to `/opt/MATLAB/R2018a/sys/os/glnxa64` causes the problem

Comment: why can't you just use the those binaries?

Comment: I am using them. But, I'd like to learn why `/opt/MATLAB/R2018a/sys/os/glnxa64` does not work? What can cause this? And how I can avoid it in future?

Comment: I do not know, you should try posting this to the mathworks forum, maybe they can be of more help. This seems to me that somewhere in those binaries there is an unhandled runtime error.  I did also see this, but this issue is beyond me https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/275176-matlab-crashes-on-startup-segmentation-violation

Comment: It's most likely the existence of `libstdc++`. Matlab and Qt may have linked to different versions of that library, so Qt now loading the one in the matlab folder leads to a crash. Try removing those two files and see if it works.

Comment: @Felix is there anyway to tell Qt to use the default path for `libstdc++`, or may be limit the foile that it uses from `/opt/MATLAB/R2018a/sys/os/glnxa64` path?

Comment: yes, you can use the LD_PRELOAD environment variable. This causes the library to be loaded before the application. sample code: `LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/actual/libstdc++ myApp` (you can find that path using ldd)

Comment: @Felix - this does fix it. If you change it to a answer, I'll mark it, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the application crashes it that Qt and matlab use different versions of `libstdc++6`. When not linking to matlab, the standard version of the library in a standard library location is beeing loaded by the linker.

However, when adding `LIBS += -L/opt/MATLAB/R2018a/sys/os/glnxa64` that path is added to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable by QtCreator. Now the linker checks that directory first and finds `libstdc++6` and loads it. Due to binary imcompatability between the two version the application crashes somewhere in Qt code.

In order to prevent this "wrong" library to be loaded, `LD_PRELOAD` can be set as environment variable to the systems `libstdc++6` version to load this one even before loading the actual application.

However, this is only a workaround and will most likely lead to crashes in matlab code, as now the `libstdc++6` beeing used is incompatible to the one matlab needs.

The only real soultion is to compile matlab from source against the systems `libstdc++6` or install it from your distros repository.

**Note:** You should propably read `README.libstdc++` - my guess it that readme can tell you a similar story